# Is using array.map in react causes systematic render of each item?

Tags: reactjs, list, optimization

I have juste notice that elements generated my an Array.map function are all re rendered each time a single element mutates. 
The followind example demonstrates the problem. I can see the element is being rerendered because od the console.log function at render time, however the useEffect functions demonstrated that props hasn't change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-flower-8shvj

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] **in the question**, but: have you provided a sensible key prop?

Comment: Actually, your code from codesandbox works fine, and in useEffect you can log value, and it'll change. Now you're just logging name. Array map is not remounting your component as long as you keep the same dom structure and keynames.

Answer (score 0):

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

As from the [React Hooks documentation](http://%20https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), the `console.log` output will show in ur console because `useEffect` will act like the classical `componentDidMount`, thus, it's a totally normal behavior of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `React.memo` as a performance optimization.

> If your function component renders the same result given the same
>   props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost
>   in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip
>   rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

[React.memo docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

```
const Item = React.memo(function Item(props) {
// function component body
});
```

In your case it is not needed, but if you want to pass a custom function as the second argument, it would look like this:

```
const Item = React.memo(function Item(props) {
// function component body
}, areEqual)

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.value === nextProps.value;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-brahmagupta-3yxjo